# Getting Flycheck to include the gtk stuff

Tags: emacs

I'm using Flycheck on my Emacs, and I'm starting to learn GTK. However, Flycheck obviously isn't aware of this stuff, and gives me errors on those `#include`s.

I've tried manually including each of the things on the include path option, but this is pretty insane - there's a huge amount there! When compiling from the command line, `pkg-config` is used precisely for this reason. Is there a way I can get Flycheck to do something similar? As it uses `gcc` as its syntax checker, I think it should be possible, I just don't know how.

Comment: Flycheck maintainer here.  Questions about Emacs and Emacs tools have a much better chance of being answered timely when asked on StackOverflow.  Many Emacs developers, including myself, use and monitor that site, but are not on Superuser.  I only accidentally noticed this question.  Had you asked on Stack Overflow, with a "flycheck" tag, I'd likely have answered it the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is in fact not possible without custom Emacs Lisp code.

There is no built-in solution for this problem in Flycheck, and there likely will never be one, because of the diversity of C/C++ build tools and systems, which all have a different approach to figure out and store compiler flags.

Hence, you need to write custom Emacs Lisp code to fill `flycheck-clang-include-path` or `flycheck-gcc-include-path` (depending on what checker you are using) with what you obtain from `pkg-config`.  I do not know Gtk, so unfortunately I cannot help you with how that code should look exactly.

Generally, you'd write a function that calls `pkg-config` and sets the variable, and add that function to `c-mode-hook`.   Take a look at the [flycheck-haskell](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck-haskell/blob/master/flycheck-haskell.el) or [flycheck-dmd-dub](https://github.com/atilaneves/flycheck-dmd-dub/blob/master/flycheck-dmd-dub.el) extensions, which set Flycheck settings for Haskell and D respectively based on the underlying build systems.

That is the best solution you get, for the lack of standardized build tools makes it impossible to provide more sophisticated support for C/C++ without a great effort.

**Disclaimer:** I am the maintainer of Flycheck.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to have flycheck leverage a project's makefile to get its flags, etc.?

Comment: @ChristopherSmith Sure, if you write the code that does that…

Comment: I was thinking something relatively simple like grabbing the standard variable flags makefile and/or invoking make with the CC or CXX environment variables set to something which intercepts the flags...